# python package installed but could not import

Tags: python, module, troposphere

I have tried to re-install and got the following message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: troposphere==1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)
```

I checked my python version and I could see this as same:

```
animjain$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

When I try to import a module, get the following error:

```
animjain$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from troposphere import Join, Ref, FindInMap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named troposphere
```

Comment: do you have more than one version of python on your machine?

Comment: yes I have multiple versions of python running. I will try to see if below things work out....if you want to add anything mean while, please :)

Comment: If you have more than one version of python running then most likely you are install the module to the wrong version

Answer (score 2):

You should use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to install dependencies for your project. You don't need to clog global site-packages.

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
cd ~
virtualenv your_test_venv
source your_test_venv/bin/activate
pip install troposphere
```

After that you can use your new package.

When you want to deactivate your virtualenv you can run command `deactivate`

Answer (score 1):

In case you have multiple Python versions on your machine, install with the same Python command, so instead of:

```
animjain$ pip install troposphere==1.8.2
```

run:

```
animjain$ python -mpip install troposphere==1.8.2
```