# Python ImportError: cannot import name dtw

Tags: python

I installed python DTW (Dynamic Time Warping) module via

```
python -m pip install dtw
```

When I try to import the module using `from dtw import dtw` (I'm following http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/pierre-rouanet/dtw/blob/master/simple%20example.ipynb) I get an `ImportError: cannot import name dtw`. I checked that `dtw.py` and `dtw.pyc` files are present in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`. Does anyone know the solution to that problem?

Comment: Have you several versions of `python` ta your computer?

Comment: Maybe it's just `import dtw`?

Comment: Check my answer from this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486550/python-package-installed-but-could-not-import/42487646#42487646

You should use virtualenv

Comment: what's the name of  working file that you saved? Hope you did not save as dtw.py. If yes, rename it to something other than dtw and try. I tried the tutorial and its working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers! @Anil_M, that was it! I named the file dtw.py and that was the breaker for me. After renaming the file the code works as expected.

Comment: @Biba, If I post my response as an answer would you accept it? That way this question will get closed. Else it will appear on SO threads as unanswered question.

Comment: Maybe try this project: https://github.com/talcs/simpledtw

Answer (score 2):

In case you are looking for speed

```
from cdtw import pydtw
from dtaidistance import dtw
from fastdtw import fastdtw
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
s1=np.array([1,2,3,4],dtype=np.double)
s2=np.array([4,3,2,1],dtype=np.double)

%timeit dtw.distance_fast(s1, s2)
4.1 µs ± 28.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit d2 = pydtw.dtw(s1,s2,pydtw.Settings(step = 'p0sym', window = 'palival', param = 2.0, norm = False, compute_path = True)).get_dist()
45.6 µs ± 3.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit d3,_=fastdtw(s1, s2, dist=euclidean)
901 µs ± 9.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

fastdtw is 219 times slower than dtaidistance lib and 20x slower than cdtw

Consider changing. Here is dtaidistance git:

https://github.com/wannesm/dtaidistance

To install, just:

```
pip install dtaidistance
```

Answer (score 0):

If we read the official docs, we find the following warning.

> Warning: The (pip) package name is dtw-python; the import statement is just import dtw.

Thus, please install dtw-python and your problem shall be solved.

https://dynamictimewarping.github.io/python/